# Search for part of an key in array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search

is it possible to search for array keys?

Let's say I've got the following array:

```
$array = array('array_one' => 'a', 'array_two' => 'b', 'three' => 'c');
```

And I just want to get this array:

```
$array = array('array_one' => 'a', 'array_two' => 'b');
```

So I want to fetch every key with its value containing the string 'array_' in the *key*.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid you have to loop with foreach and look for key values.

Comment: `preg_grep()` may help, but you'd probably be better off restructuring the array when you build it to make it more usable for the way you want to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a negative filter (with [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)) instead:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'array_') !== 0) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tDGJYg)

Note that it modifies the array in-place.

**Update**

Or, since 5.6 you can now use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$array = array_filter($array, function($value, $key) {
    return strpos($key, 'array_') === 0;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_filter` on the keys and then intersect:

```
$validKeys = array_filter(array_keys($array),
    function($key) {
        return substr($key, 0, 6) === 'array_';
    }
);

$array = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($validKeys));
```

Comment: Not very efficient... a loop over the original array (non needed) just for creating a new array of keys (not needed), plus the intersection...

Comment: @Gremo: you are right, *should* performance become an issue here (large arrays), a single foreach will improve it.

Answer (score 3):

To filter *statically* you can use [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php):

```
$allowed = array('foo', 'bar');
$filtered = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($allowed));
```

In your case I think you need to loop:

```
$filtered = array();

foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if(false !== strpos($key, 'array_')) {
        $filtered[$key] = $val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of a `foreach` loop:

```
$search='_array';
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {

    if (strpos($a, $search)!==false) echo "$search is in $k!<br />";

}
```