# How to search php array for a string, but only within a specific key?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called `$myarray` that might look like this:

```
Array
(
    [221] => suspended-suspended-1
    [691] => knee-ir-1
    [812] => knee-ir-4
)
```

Below, I am checking to see if an id exists as a key (691 for example) and if so, I then want to do another check to see if the string "ir" exists for that key.  Not just anywhere in the array, it has to be next to 691, for example (i.e. on the specific line).

```
$row['id']=691; //for example

if (array_key_exists($row['id'], $myarray)) {  
    if (in_array("ir", $myarray)){
        //ill do some stuff here if "ir" exists         
    } else {
    }
}
```

Obviously, what I wrote will look for "ir" anywhere in the array, but how do I look only within the info associated with key "691"?

Comment: Related: [Search for part of an key in array - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15139259/8958173)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `isset()` and `strpos()` to simplify your code

```
$row['id']=691; //for example

if(isset($myarray[$row['id']]) && strpos($myarray[$row['id']],"ir") !==false){
  //ill do some stuff here if "ir" exists 
}
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/5CrLW

Note:- if you want to check exact value on that index (that is given index value is `ir` or not)the use  `==`

Output:-https://3v4l.org/U7bHg

Comment: In PHP7 `if(strpos($myarray[$row['id']] ?? "","ir") !==false){` is even simpler

Answer (score 1):

```
$myarray = Array(
            [221] => suspended-suspended-1 
            [691] => knee-ir-1 
            [812] => knee-ir-4 
            ); 
    if(isset($myarray){ 
        if (in_array("-ir", $myarray)) { 
            //ill do some stuff here if "ir" exists 
        }else{ 
            //ill do some stuff here if "ir" exists 
        } 
    } 
}
```