# Search part of array key on PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have the following output when printing an array called yestardayArray using print_r:

```
Array
(
    [project-id] => Array
        (
            [373482] => Array
                (
                    [responsible-ids] => Array
                        (
                            [171812,129938] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [task-id] => 18055196
                                            [content] => HU-002 
                                            [responsible-ids] => 171812,129938
                                        )

                                )

                            [171812] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [task-id] => 18055300
                                            [content] => HU-002
                                            [responsible-ids] => 171812
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [task-id] => 18055307
                                            [content] => HU-002 - BACK 
                                            [responsible-ids] => 171812
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I'm iterating througth project-id (using the variable $pid), in the case of this example "373482", and also iterating througth responsible-ids with $key. As $key i'm using all the posible responsible-ids values for the project to get a match and do some stuff.

That work great in the case that there is only one responsible (because there is a full match), but if there are more, like in "171812,129938" there is no match.

**How would you validate if $key (171812 or 129938) is part of responsible-ids ("171812,129938")?**

I tried to convert the array key to a string, in order to use built-in php search functions like substr_count or strpos.

```
$needString = $yesterdayArray["project-id"][$pid]["responsible-ids"][$key];
```

But when I print needString I get "Array" instead of "171812,129938".

What can I do?

Comment: This is a horrible design. Array keys shouldn't be in a format that requires matching, they should be something you can use as a direct lookup.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I changed the keys to have only one value on responsible-ids to avoid comma separated values

Comment: Somewhat related: [Search for part of an key in array - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15139259/8958173)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `explode()` on the keys, and then use `in_array()` to check if `$key` is in the array.

```
foreach ($yesterdayArray["project-id"] as $pid => $project) {
    foreach ($project["responsible-ids"] as $resp_ids => $tasks) {
        $resp_id_array = explode(',', $resp_id);
        if (in_array($key, $resp_id_array)) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```